# Proving the given inequality(Probability theory).

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We're given a random variable $X$ with $E(X)= \mu$ and $P(X\leq0) = 0$ , we need to show that $P(X>2\mu) \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

What I think is , since no distribution is given for $X$ , somehow Chebyshev's inequality should be used here which states : $$ P(|X- E(X)| > r\sigma_x)\geq 1- \frac{1}{r^2}$$ where $\sigma_X$ is the standard deviation for $X$ , $r>0$.

But only $E(X)$ is provided here , is Chebyshev's inequality appropriate choice for this question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $P(X \le 0)=0$ condition should be a hint to use Markov's inequality.

Comment: Got it . Thanks ! 
So foolish of me , stuck to the chebyshev's inequality only. :P